# How can we do a Gaussian integral over matrix elements?

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral, random-matrices

I am integrating the following Gaussian over all possible matrix elements $J_{ij}$:
$$ I=\int \exp{\left\{-a\sum_{ij}J_{ij}^2+b\sum_{ij}J_{ij}+c\sum_{ij}J_{ij}J_{ji} \right\}} \left (\prod_{ij}\mathrm{d}J_{ij} \right)$$

How can I deal with the $\sum_{ij}J_{ij}J_{ji}$ terms? The fact that I am integrating over matrix elements confuses me. Any help or advice is always appreciated, thanks !